# What is the sum of all values $p$ satisfying this equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Consider the following equation:

$$\frac{n^3-12n^2+8n+93}{11+2n-n^2} = p$$

Let $n$ be some integer satisfying above equation yielding a prime number $p$. What is the sum of all possible values of $p$?

Comment: i couldn't find anything please help ,this is my first post

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your post and share what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks i didnt know that i so didint know the approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You can use that $$\frac{n^3-12n^2+8n+93}{11+2n-n^2}=-n+10+{\frac {n+17}{{n}^{2}-2\,n-11}}$$

Comment: It does, compute the $n$ when $$11+2n-n^2$$ is positive, for these $n$ is $$n^3-12n^2+8n+93$$ negative, so your term can not be a prime.

Comment: ok thanks i got it